# Загрузка библиотеки

Tags: java, библиотеки, dll

Доброго времени суток! Я удалил dll-ки из System32, но программа все равно выдает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path
...........
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\opencv_core245.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
```

в чем дело?

Comment: Проверьте заодно в C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Comment: точно. спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Ответ из комментария [@Антон Феоктистов](/users/357/):

Проверьте заодно в `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

--

Возможная причина наблюдаемого явления - [автоматическое перенаправление](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx) обращений 32-битного процесса к `%windir%\system32\` в `%windir\syswow64\`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет

```
regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\System32\opencv_core245.dll
```

но не гарантирую

Answer (score -1):

> Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

А что трудно перевести? У вас 32-х разрядная система, в которую вы пытаетесь загрузить 64-х разрядную библиотеку.

Comment: прочитайте вопрос - проблема в том, что я удалил эту библиотеку. должно выдавать ошибку, что ее нет в java.library.path

Comment: Это вы так думаете, но лог однозначно выдает что у вас проблема в другом - подумайте еще раз :)